# Is it standard to write $2>1>0$?

Tags: article-writing

Is it standard to write $2>1>0$ or we should write $2>1$ and $1>0$?

Comment: First is shorthand for second.

Comment: It's unambiguous; I do it and I think it's fine.

Comment: It is indeed fine. But you should be aware that in practice, the same information is more often conveyed by writing $0<1<2$.

Comment: There is no ambiguity in $0>1>2.$ (On the other hand, [$p⇒q⇒r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260588/21813) might mean either $$p⇒(q⇒r)$$ or $$(p⇒q)⇒r$$ or $$(p⇒q)\text{ and }(q⇒r),$$ no pair of which is logically equivalent.)