# Is $( (\lnot p \lor q ) \lor ( p \lor r ) )$ equivalent to $( \lnot p \lor q \lor p \lor r )$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Determine whether $( p \land q ) \to ( p \lor ( q \land r ) )$ is tautology or not.

In line 5 of my given picture can I write this

$( (\lnot p \lor q ) \lor ( p \lor r ) )$  as  $( \lnot p \lor q \lor p \lor r )$

If yes then what is this rule called?

My solution:

[image: My solution pic1]

Comment: The statement at the top of your image is immediately a tautology, simply because assuming $p \land q$ one can immediately get $p$ and hence $p \lor x$ where $x$ is anything. By the way getting just $p$ starting with $p \land q$ is sometimes called "simplification on the first conjunct."

Comment: In my opinion this is correct. You could also do an extensive truth table, which is not too much effort, but a guaranteed way of avoiding mistakes (or learning something...).

Comment: That means my line 5 is correct, right? @Cornman

Comment: Yes, all you did was using commutativity.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In line 5 of my given picture, can I write this?
>
> $\quad\bigg( (\lnot p \lor q ) \lor ( p \lor r ) \bigg)$  as  $\bigg( \lnot p \lor q \lor p \lor r \bigg)$
>
> If yes then what is this rule called?

It's called the [generalised associative law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Generalized_associative_law):

> If a binary operation is associative, repeated application of the
> operation produces the same result regardless of how valid pairs of
> parentheses are inserted in the expression. This is called the
> generalized associative law.
>
> For instance, a product of four elements
> may be written, without changing the order of the factors, in five
> possible ways: $${\displaystyle ((ab)c)d}\tag1$$
> $${\displaystyle (ab)(cd)}\tag2$$
> $${\displaystyle (a(bc))d}\tag3$$
> $${\displaystyle a((bc)d)}\tag4$$
> $${\displaystyle a(b(cd))}\tag5$$ If the product
> operation is associative, the generalized associative law says that
> all these formulas will yield the same result. So, unless [the formula with omitted parentheses already has a different meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260588/21813), the
> parentheses can be considered unnecessary and "the" product can be
> written unambiguously as $${\displaystyle abcd.}\tag6$$

Here, you've rewritten $(2)$ as $(6),$ which implicitly means $(5).$