# Logic question - just to clear up meaning of 'implies'

Tags: logic

Okay so;

I have the following statement

$p \lor \neg q \Rightarrow q \lor \neg q$

I simplify the right hand side using the complement law to get

$p \lor \neg q \Rightarrow T $

I think that $\neg q \lor p$ is the same as saying $q \Rightarrow p$ ,

so does **q imply p imply true?**

Will this statement always be true? I think it does; and my thinking behind it is that since q implies p, then it will either output true or false? And since the other side of the implication is **always true** then either false of true implies true, correct?

Comment: "I think that ¬q∨p is the same as saying q⇒p ," Yes, see [Material implication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))

Comment: "Will this statement always be true?" No, of course $q \to p$ is not always TRUE: check with truth table. Thins are different for $(q \to p) \to \top$; this is a conditional with TRUE consequent and in this case it is always TRUE.

Comment: To the OP (i.e. original poster): I agree with your analysis.  That is, if you have a statement $S$ that is always true, then any statement of the form $(R \implies S)$ can not be false (since $S$ is assumed always true).

Comment: See [Logical implication](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Logical_implication#Definition) as well as the related concept of [Logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both

$$(q \Rightarrow p) \Rightarrow T$$
and
$$
(q \Rightarrow p) \Leftrightarrow (\neg q \lor p)
$$
are true.

Intuitively, the value $T$ holds for any premise (since it always holds), as you said. You can check the truth table of these formulas, if in doubt.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of the dual of the principle of explosion (or vacuous truth) which states that all things follow from a falsehood:

$~~~~~~A \implies (\neg A \implies B)$

Here you have, a truth follows from all things:

$~~~~~~A\implies (B \implies A)$

Both are tautologies and are legitimate methods of proof.

Answer (score 0):

1. > so does **q imply p imply true?**

   Note that this phrasing is potentially ambiguous, because [the conditional $(\to)$ is not associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260588/21813), that is, $$(A → B) → C \:\not\equiv\: A → (B → C).$$ \begin{array}{ccc|c@{}c@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}c@{}c}
   a&b&c&(&(&(&a&\rightarrow&b&)&\rightarrow&c&)&\leftrightarrow&(&a&\rightarrow&(&b&\rightarrow&c&)&)&)\\\hline
   1&1&1&&&&1&1&1&&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&&1&1&1&&&\\
   1&1&0&&&&1&1&1&&0&0&&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&&1&0&0&&&\\
   1&0&1&&&&1&0&0&&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&&0&1&1&&&\\
   1&0&0&&&&1&0&0&&1&0&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&&0&1&0&&&\\
   0&1&1&&&&0&1&1&&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&&1&1&1&&&\\
   0&1&0&&&&0&1&1&&0&0&&\mathbf{0}&&0&1&&1&0&0&&&\\
   0&0&1&&&&0&1&0&&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&&0&1&1&&&\\
   0&0&0&&&&0&1&0&&0&0&&\mathbf{0}&&0&1&&0&1&0&&&
   \end{array}
2. Notice that a conditional $X\to Y$ is true whenever its consequent $Y$ is true: \begin{array}{cc|c@{}ccc@{}c}
   X&Y&(&X&\rightarrow&Y&)\\\hline
   1&1&&1&\mathbf{1}&1&\\
   1&0&&1&\mathbf{0}&0&\\
   0&1&&0&\mathbf{1}&1&\\
   0&0&&0&\mathbf{1}&0&
   \end{array} Therefore, since the given proposition $$p \lor \neg q \;\to\; q \lor \neg q$$ has a tautological (always-true) consequent, it is immediately also a tautology, that is, always true. \begin{array}{cc|c@{}c@{}ccc@{}cc@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}cc@{}c@{}c@{}c}
   p&q&(&(&p&\lor&(&\lnot&q&)&)&\rightarrow&(&q&\lor&(&\lnot&q&)&)&)\\\hline
   1&1&&&1&1&&0&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&&0&1&&&\\
   1&0&&&1&1&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&&1&0&&&\\
   0&1&&&0&0&&0&1&&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&&0&1&&&\\
   0&0&&&0&1&&1&0&&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&&1&0&&&
   \end{array}