# Prove that $p \implies (q \lor (\neg r \implies p)) \equiv q \lor r$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

As per the title, im asked to Prove that $p \implies (q \lor (\neg r \implies p)) \equiv q \lor r$.

However, im stuck on this logical equivalence question, my working so far is as follows;

$$p \implies (q \lor (\neg r \implies p)) \equiv \neg p \lor (q \lor r\lor p)$$

$$\equiv (\neg p \lor p) \lor (q \lor r)$$

Would this not be just a tautology?, whereas $q \lor r$ is not?

Comment: That seems correct to me - can you ensure that you've copied the question correctly?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > $p \implies (q \lor (\neg r \implies p)) \equiv q \lor r$
>
> im stuck on this logical equivalence question

Neither $$P → \bigg((Q ∨ (¬R → P)) ↔ Q ∨ R\bigg)\tag1$$ nor $$\bigg(P → (Q ∨ (¬R→P))\bigg) ↔ Q∨R.\tag2$$ is actually logically valid.

P.S. I'm suggesting sentence $(1)$ in case the author is treating $→/\Rightarrow$ and $↔/≡$ as being *collectively* [right-associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260588/21813).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
p \implies (q \lor (\neg r \implies p)) &\equiv \neg p \lor (q \lor r\lor p) \hspace{0.4cm} \text{Using }(p\implies q)\iff (\neg p\lor q)\\
&\equiv (\neg p \lor p) \lor (q\lor r) \hspace{0.4cm} \text{Associativity and commutativity of }\lor\\
\end{align}

$(\neg p\lor p)$ is a tautology, if $p$ is true, its negation is wrong, and so the ($\neg p\lor p$) is always true. Meaning that the formula is a tautology.

Thanks to @insipidintegrator for the remark.

Comment: But isn’t A $\lor$ B a tautology if A is already determined to be true?

Comment: ($\neg p \lor p) $ is always a tautology. Let M: q$\lor$ r so ($\neg p \lor p) \lor M$ is always a tautology

Comment: @insipidintegrator I was out of this world for few hours today. Thanks !