# Logics; Proof by contradiction (specific question)

Tags: logic

In mathematics it is not possible to derive something wrong when my premise is true. So my question is, is this the reason when i do have a contradiction that i assume my premise had to be wrong, since then it is true again. So we always want true assumptions ?

Comment: as an example i can say that f differntiable => it is continous. And not the other way around. So if i assume when f is continous and want to show that is differentiable is this not possible. Thus f continous implies f differentiable is wrong ?

Comment: so wouldnt i have a contradiction If f is continous i don't have that f is differentiable then i could say f is continous would be wrong hence f would not be continous ?! but f is continous ?

Comment: Suppose you go like $A$ implies $B$ implies $C$ with each step correct, and say $C$ is wrong. Since every step you followed was correct, the only possible way the contradiction occurred because your premise was wrong(all other steps were correct).

Comment: See also the post [Justification of Proofs by Contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49552/justification-of-proofs-by-contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your comments. But a proof by contradiction usually goes like this: You suppose something is true, then show that it is wrong. That, or you give a counterexample.

For example, a continuous function is not necessarily differentiable. Take $f(x) = |x|$ as a counterexample.

A well-used example is the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: yeah exactly. But i assume f is continous and show that f is not differntiable. Would that be a contradiction ? Hence i can say f is continous would be wrong but this is not the case

Comment: @MahtsGuy  That's assuming your premise is true in the first place.

Comment: i will try again to explain that: So i assume f is continous and want to show f is differentiable(this not true) this is not possible hence i have a contradiction and therefore f is continous must be wrong? But f can be continous

Comment: No, the entire statement $f$ continuous $\Rightarrow f$ differentiable is false.

Comment: i know but why ?

Comment: "But i assume f is continuous and show that f is not differentiable." I don't understand what you mean by that.  **Some** continuous functions *are* differentiable.  If you mean you have a specific continuous function and show it is not differentiable (for example f(x)= |x|) that is not "contradicting" anything.

Comment: To be clear: f is continous $\Rightarrow $ f is differentiable. Is wrong (I KNOW). But I assume f is continous and show that f is not differentiable. So i do have a contradiction or dont i? and thus my premise would be wrong. But this cannot be the case

Comment: exactly what @user247327 said, there are quantifiers. When you say continuity implies differentiability, this is a statement saying that $\textbf{all}$ continuous functions are differentiable.

Comment: If you assume that(your premise) all $f$ are continuous(meaning, $f$ can be anything) then you cannot actually show that they are  not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two implications.
a sure and a not sure.

If $P$ is true and the implication $P\implies Q$ is sure, then we are sure that $Q$ is true.

If $P$ is true and the implication $P\implies Q$ is not sure, then we can say nothing about $Q$.

If the implication is sure and $Q$ is false, this means that $P$ is false.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Could you explain in longer phrases