# Deriving Universal Modus Tollens

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm asked to derive the validity of Universal Modus Tollens from the validity of Universal Instantiation and Modus Tollens.  I'm new to this deriving/proving stuff, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, but here's what I came up with:

Universal instantiation says that if (1) is true:

```
(1) ∀x, P(x) → Q(x)
```

Then (2) is true for any particular item y

```
(2) P(y) → Q(y)
```

Modus Tollens says that if (2) is true and (3) is true:

```
(3) ~Q(y)
```

Then (4) is true:

```
(4) ~P(y)
```

Therefore if (1) is true, and (3) is true, then (4) is true. In other words, the following argument is valid:

```
∀x, P(x) → Q(x)
~Q(y)
∴ ~P(y)
```

And that's Universal Modus Tollens.

Am I doing this right?  Am I making any unwarranted assumptions or unsupported claims?  Am I skipping any steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a little logic magic, shall we?

**Note:** I will assume here "$\implies$" is identical with "$\rightarrow$", and therefore that you are *asserting* the proposition in (1) rather than merely considering it. See discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_implication#Philosophical_issues) for a reason why.

Let the set $S$ be the set of those elements, $x$, such that statements such as "$P(x)$" or "$Q(x)$"  make sense and for such statements it makes sense to consider the propositions of the form "$P(x) \implies Q(x)$".

Consider then, since:

$$
\tag{1} \forall x \in S,P(x) \implies Q(x),
$$

$$
(1) \iff \tag{2} \forall x \in S, (\text{~}P(x) \vee Q(x)) \text{ is true.}
$$

Asserting:

$$
\tag{3} \exists y \in S, \text{~}Q(x) \text{ is true},
$$

we get,

$$
\tag{4} (\text{~}Q(x) \text{ is true}) \implies (\text{~}P(x) \text{ is true}).
$$

For the sake of brevity, I'm skipping a step here; though it is admittedly trivial.

Therefore,

$$
\tag{5} (1) \wedge (3) \implies \text{~}P(x) \text{ is true}.
$$

Q.E.D.

**EDIT:**

So, to answer your questions:

1. You have this right.
2. For most purposes, you have no problem with assumptions.
3. Finally, you skipped a step between (3) and (4) in your post, which was made explicit by (2) in mine.

On a side note, for future reference, using $\LaTeX$ would probably be a better alternative to inserting mathematical notation in your posts on SE.

TIP: You can tag your equations by using "\tag{n}", where "n" denotes the number or string you want to tag your equation with.

Comment: I edited the 3rd list item, I had referred to the wrong lines.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for being late to the game, but here goes:

[image]

Since [image] due to the identity rule, then [image]. Now distribute [image] to get [image].

[image] is a contradiction, or a negation law. Thus [image].

So we now have [image].

we can now use the identity law of [image], assuming [image]. Thus [image]

[image] is the definition of Decomposing a conjunction in the laws of Tautology. Please refer to page 7 of the following link: http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/math-proof/truth-tables/truth-tables.pdf