# Choosing between Conjunction and Implication

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say I want to express this statement using quantifiers : 
"For every two odd numbers, the sum of them is even."

$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$  ( $(O(x)$ AND $O(y)$) $\rightarrow E(x+y)  )$

where $O(x)$ means $x$ is odd, and $E(x)$ means $x$ is even.

My question is, is the expression correct ? I think there may be an error whenever either $O(x)$ or $O(y)$ is false, since it will make the whole implication correct.
But I just don't know how to express it in another way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. You're right that, if (say) we take $x=2$ and $y=3$, the inner implication winds up being true - but that's a *good* thing: it means "what if $x=2$ and $y=3$?" **isn't** a counterexample to the statement (it's not a counterexample because $x$ isn't odd - it's like if you said, "There are no consecutive primes bigger than 3" and I said, "What about 2 and 3?").

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474054.

Comment: Thank you,it really made sense!