# Propositional Logic: Entailment

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to understand propositional logics and the concepts of entailment, but I'm struggling. The concepts don't seem to be difficult in theory, but are very strange-looking when examined. For example, I understand that the formal definition of entailment is that `a ⊨ b iff M(a) ⊆ M(b)`.

However, the first example that my textbook provides is that `false ⊨ true` but `true ⊭ false`. I'm struggling to understand how false can entail true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Natural language**: $a$ entails $b$ if, whenever $a$ is true, $b$ is true.

**Models**: $a$ entails $b$ if every model of $a$ is a model of $b$ - that is, if $M(a)\subseteq M(b)$.

So think about "$\perp$" ("false"). When is $\perp$ true? Or, what is the set of models of $\perp$?

---

It may be easier to think about the following set-theoretic problem first:

> Why is $\emptyset\subseteq A$ for every set $A$?

Comment: So stated another way (with regards to the `false ⊨ true` but `true ⊭ false` example)  -- the absence of evidence doesn't preclude the possibility of occurrence, but evidence of occurrence precludes the impossibility of occurrence?

Comment: Um, I don't quite follow that - I think you're trying a bit too hard. Consider this. Suppose your child comes up to you and says, "Can I have dessert before dinner if Santa Claus exists?" You wouldn't have a problem saying "yes," since - because Santa doesn't exist - you would not be hurting your child's nutrition. :P That is, the sentence "If Santa exists, then I can have dessert before dinner" ("false implies true") is true. This isn't an exact parallel, but I think it will make things clearer.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you think this is weird, you've got a point: consider the sentence "If I am not the prime minister of Lichtenstein, then this statement is false." Natural language and formal logic don't mix very well (or I've been shirking my duties).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474054/implication-in-mathematics-how-can-a-imply-b-when-a-is-false/1474063#1474063.

Comment: @wadda_wadda Basically, a valid argument beginning from a `false` premise *may* lead to a `true` conclusion ($\bot\vDash\top$, or $\bot\vDash\bot$), but a valid argument beginning from `true` premises *can not* lead to a `false` conclusion ($\top\nvDash\bot$).