# A confusing proof (which is wrong) to show $x^2 + 1 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently, I found out someone has tried to prove that $x^2 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, Here is the detail:

\begin{align*} 
x^2 + 1 = 0 \\
(x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1) = 0(x^2 - 1)\\
x^4 - 1 = 0 \\
x^4 = 1\\
\Longrightarrow x \in \{-1,1\}
\end{align*}

This is a repaired version of the original he threw at me, after I point out that it is wrong. The original one use the notation "$\Longrightarrow$" to assume his multiplication. Here is how it looks like:

\begin{equation*}
x^2 + 1 = 0 \Longrightarrow (x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1) = 0(x^2 - 1) \Longrightarrow x^4 - 1 = 0 \Longrightarrow x^4 = 1
\end{equation*}

From my knowledge of logic theory to the very least, by the way of using "$\Longrightarrow$", you are "implying" something. Suppose that we are given two statements, $A$ and $B$. $A ⇒ B$ means that you are implying that "If $A$ then $B$", or from $A$ you implies that $B$ is something like this or that. The statement $A⇒B$ doesn't make any claim about whether $B$ also implies $A$. Therefore, even if for a "wrong" transformation, the statement $B$ does not implies that it will be applied inversely to $A$, thus the prove is likely to be nothing. This is already discussed in [this post on MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474054/implication-in-mathematics-how-can-a-imply-b-when-a-is-false):

> The statement $A⇒B$ doesn't make any claim about whether $B$ also implies $A$. Defining it this way makes certain things a lot easier, since we can now say (e.g.) $x>7⇒x>5$. This is a true mathematical statement $(A⇒B)$ for real x. In other words, $A⇒B$ is true. But what if we let $x=6$? Now $B$ is true but $A$ is false; yet you'd still agree that $A⇒B$ is true. It just so happens that $A$ is false in this one case; that doesn't impact the overall truth or falsehood of $A⇒B$.

Now that's is for the "original" proof he gave me. After that, he typically "fix" it, by reading it as purely as a algebraic manipulation task. This is my least trial of proving he is wrong.

- First, the statement is already false, geometrically. To "prove" that $x^2 + 1 = 0$ basically means you are solving to find where the function $f: x \longmapsto x^2 + 1$ cross the x-axis. $x^2 + 1$ from the beginning has the $+1$ as the translation up, that is, the vertex will always be $(1,0)$, and considering that this is a even quadratic function, it is unlikely that there will be any intersection even if you tried to search for it along all $\mathbb{R}$
- Second, multiplying anything with $0$ will result in $0$. By "factor" out $x^2 -1$ from both side is wrong, since you are altering the solution sets of the total equation.
- Last, *don't use what you are wanting to prove to prove itself.* If you use itself to prove it, then it is similar as you are assuming it, therefore, you don't have to prove it anymore.

The question here is: Am I right, how can I fix my reasoning if I was wrong, and what is your attempt to de-prove his proof?

Comment: You have multiplied by $x^2-1$ in the second line, so by zero for $x=\pm 1$. This is not allowed.

Comment: $x-1=0$ so $(x-1)(x-2)=0$ so $x=1$ or $x=2.$ What you've shown is that if $x^2+1=0$ and $x$ is real, then $x=\pm1.$ But that's because there is no real solution to $x^2+1=0.$

Comment: In other words, imagine taking $5=3$ (which is false), multiplying by $0$ on both sides, arriving at $0=0$ (which is true), and thinking that you've proven something deep.

Comment: You should have $\longleftrightarrow$ for each step instead of $\rightarrow$. Can you see at which step it fails if you move backward?

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb R$, then the equation $x^2=-a \ \ \forall \ a\geq 0$ has no solution. A squared number is always positive, as an area of a square is positive.

Comment: This argument correctly shows: if $x$ is a real solution of $x^2+1=0$, then $x \in \{-1,1\}$.  That is correct.   But of course an "if/then" statement $P \rightarrow Q$ is true when $P$ is false.  This is what happens for any real number $x$.

Comment: @Randall this is not my proof, it's only a thing that I met but kind of confused of how he could come up with the proof. Still, thanks for clarify me.

Comment: @Etemon I just copy the original proof, and it is exactly what it is up there.

Comment: The final step picks out only two of the four solutions to the quartic - they happen to be the two that do not solve the original quadratic. [in this context] If $p(x)q(x)=0$ then $p(x)=0$ or $q(x)=0$, but it does not follow that if $p(x)=0$ then $q(x)=0$.

Comment: Is it clear to you that if you set $x=\pm1$ that $x^2+1=2?$

Comment: @DietrichBurde Multiplying by $0$ is allowed. The resulting statement is not equivalent to the original one, but one implication is valid and that can be useful.

Comment: You should us MathJax also in the title.

Comment: @jjagmath Sorry, I wanted to say "Multiplying by 0 is not allowed for equivalence". I was assuming that we speak about equivalent equations.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks, this is my first time so I am very thankful for your advice.

Comment: I came across this question when I was doing the close vote. But I really like this question and the comments. Let’s keep it open :)

Answer (score -1):

Consider this only equation/condition :
$x^4 = 1$

The solutions of this equation are : $±1$ and $±i$ .

Now, consider these equations/conditions: $x$ must be $1$
and $x$ satisfy $x^2 = 1$ .

Now if you solve only condition 2 i.e. $x^2 = 1$ , you'll get that $x = ±1$; however you cannot claim that "*I have disproved condition first that $x$ must be $1$*" because $x$ is not $1$

Similarily , you have assumed previously that $x = ±1$ is not a solution of $x^2 = 1$ ( because these values don't satisfy it ) . And hence , if you later get these values as solutions of a modified/another equation , you cannot claim that it is the solution of previous problem .

Comment: What has $x^2=1$ to do with $x^2+1=0$ ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @KurtG. Of course nothing . I had just used a different and simpler example than original.

Comment: @Community I have just used another and simpler example to show what steps the OP is taking .