# Possible book correction or am I missing something?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, predicate-logic, real-numbers

Hi I am teaching myself analysis and bought "Analysis - With an introduction to Proof" by Steven R. Lay. Now one of the practice problems is "Determine the truth value of each statement, assuming x, y and z are real numbers"
$$
\forall x, \exists y \, and \, \exists z \, such\,  that\, z>y\, implies\, that\, z>x+y
$$

Now the solution manual says 
"True. Take z<=y. This makes "z>y" false so that the implication is true."
Now I find this "solution" troubling because I thought the whole idea behind proving an implication was to assume the antecedent IS true. Is this a mistake by the author?

Comment: See [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) and see [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30437/why-in-an-inconsistent-axiom-system-every-statement-is-true-for-dummies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a mistake; [see the truth table here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication).

The main idea is that in the logical implication $p\Rightarrow q$, if $p$ is false, then the implication does not actually promise anything about $q$. My math prof at the time told the class: irrelevance does not imply falsehood.

In your problem, $z$ and $y$ are preceded by existential quantifiers, so we can *choose* $z$ and $y$, and thus we choose $z$ and $y$ such that $z\le y$, making the implication true.

Comment: It would be better if you typed out a little bit of what's in the link.

Comment: I don't understand what makes the "p" part false in this example. What is wrong with saying there exists a pair (y,z) such that if z>y then z>x+y

Comment: Are you sure you have the question correct? I am looking at Lay 2.6(f) and it asks $\forall x$ and $\forall y$, $\exists z$ such that $z>y$ implies that $z>x+y$.

Comment: Its question 2.5(f) (from 4th edition)

Comment: I have edited my answer above.

Comment: Sorry can you explain what the "p" part of the statement is considered false. I think I am starting to understand what is going on, but im a little confused if the problem stems from the "p" part being wrong from how the statement was quantified or if it was because we were able to violate the z>y because we were able to choose z

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the difference between the two alternatives you provided, we were able to choose $z\le y$ *because* of the quantifiers, making the statement $z>y$ false.

Comment: @ErikMiehling You're wrong. You don't interpret the statement correctly, because you don't give importance to the priority of quantifiers over the implication. There is also a $\forall x$ that has to be used.

Comment: Recall that the universal quantifier can be distributed across an implication, that is, $\forall x (P\Rightarrow Q) \equiv \forall x P \Rightarrow \forall x Q$. Using this, we can see that the original problem can equivalently be written as $(\forall x \exists y\exists z \text{ such that } z>y) \Rightarrow (\forall x\, z>x+y)$. Now, following my answer above, we can choose $z$ and $y$ to make the implication true.

Comment: You're right @ErikMiehling, sorry.

Comment: No problem, the discussion helped clear up some of the loose ends.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I do not get a lot of time to work on this stuff and have recently come back to this. And really the only part of confusion I have left is -what rule of inference allowed you to assume that z<=y. Existential instantiation does not allow you to instantiate a variable...and I believe it also requires an introduction of a brand New symbol that does not appear in the premises or conclusion. So what gives?