# Conditional statements explanation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm really confused with conditional statements.

For example, given $P(x) \to Q(x)$. Actually it's equivalent to $\lnot P(x) \lor Q(x)$, right? It's easy to understand its true value - only when $P(x)$ is true and $Q(x)$ is false, the statement is false, otherwise it's true.

However, it's hard to understand in concept. Why when $P(x)$ is false, the statement is unconditionally true? How to understand 'true' here?

Given a more detailed example: $P(x)$ is 'x is man' and $Q(x)$ is 'x is rich'. When x is not a man, the value is true, but for what? What is true here?

Comment: You can see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718925/implications-and-ordinary-language).

Comment: The equivalence $\neg [ P(x) \land \neg Q(x)]$ is more intuitive. I don't know why they keep using the disjunctive form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material implication is considered to hold if and only if it guarantees that the consequent is true whenever the antecedent is.

It makes *no claim* on the consequent's truth-hood when the antecedent is false.   So if the antecedent is false the implication is said to be true *whatever* the consequent is.

So if the implication holds, then we know that *either* the antecedent is false *or else* the consequent must be true.

$$A\to C \iff \neg A\vee C$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your example : let *$P(X):X$ is a man* and *$Q(X):X$ is rich*.

Now let's take a rich dragon, $X_0$. We have that $P(X_0)$ is false and $Q(X_0)$ is true.

What we are saying is that $P(X_0)\Rightarrow\text{ anything}$. That is because $P(X_0)$ is **false**, and therefore supposing that it is true leads to any conclusion you want.