# Confused about saying every "statement" is vacuously true in an inconsistent arithmetic (terminology)

Tags: logic, terminology, definition, propositional-calculus

I am confused about the sense in which every statement is vacuously true in an inconsistent arithmetic. My lecture notes say

> The first question above asks whether it is possible to prove both a proposition P and its negation ¬P. If
> this is the case, then we say that arithmetic is inconsistent; otherwise, we say arithmetic is consistent. If
> arithmetic is inconsistent, meaning there are false statements that can be proved, then the entire arithmetic
> system will collapse because from a false statement we can deduce anything, so every statement in our
> system will be vacuously true.

It seems that it should say "every statement is the consequent in a vacuously true statement" instead. I am confused because the statements that it refers to as being vacuously true aren't necessarily implications, yet I thought that vacuous truths are true implications of the form $p \implies q$ where $q$ is false. Is it correct to say, "every statement is the consequent in a vacuously true implication, namely the implication whose antecedent is $P$", rather than saying that every statement is a vacuous truth? Based on the notes's phrasing, a statement like "My name is Sam" seems to be a possible vacuous truth. Does "vacuously true" not need to refer only to implications?

Comment: I agree with your perflexity... False statements are false and true ones are true. What an *inconsistent* theory does is that it is not able to provide us with a "tool" (the proof) to separate the true from the false ones.

Comment: I don't think you need to read the use of "vacuous" here so literally or precisely. I think the intended meaning is clear, that every statement is provable (I would not say "true") for vacuous reasons (the principle of explosion).

Comment: It's perhaps not the best wording if one insists on the rigorous definition of "vacuous truth" given above, but is still technically correct: an inconsistent system proves that every statement is equivalent to an implication $p \rightarrow q$ so that $\neg p$ is true, and is therefore vacuously true.

Comment: Paraphrasing Bram28's answer: the explicit version of "every statement is vacuously true" is "*under the assumption of inconsistent axioms,* every statement is vacuously true." -) $\quad$ P.S. This answer might also be of interest: [Is every statement of an inconsistent theory true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40257/21813)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just s function of how we talk about theorems in mathematics in general. That is, whenever we prove something in mathematics we regard that theorem to be ‘true’ … though you are right in that what we really do is ‘merely’ show that that theorem is a consequence of the axioms we are assuming.

In other words, we go from ‘is a consequence of the axioms that we use to define arithmetic’ to ‘is true in the world of arithmetic’ to ‘arithmetically true’ … to just plain ‘true’.