# What is the difference between asserting "$\phi(a)$" and asserting "$\phi(a)$ is true" in Whitehead and Russell's PM?

Tags: logic, math-history, philosophy

The first edition of Principia Mathematica clearly distinguishes "Socrates is a man" and "'Socrates is a man' is true." Judging from the context, the distinction is neither a primitive idea nor a definition; it is something the reader is supposed to **"see."** For some reason I can't **"see"** it, although I can deliberately **memorize** the distinction the same way I memorize multiplication table. I have an inkling that this distinction should directly appeal to the sense, like the distinction between red and blue. If you can **"see"** this distinction, please kindly help me out.

The following passage is from page 41, Introduction, Chapter II, section II, *The Nature of Propositional Functions.*
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejGD1.png

These symbols are for your convenience:

propositional function: $\phi(\hat{z})$

Ambiguous value: $   \phi(z) $

A function with itself as an argument: $\phi(\phi(\hat{z}))$

Comment: It seems to say "quadruplicity drinks procrastination" is nonsensical; but "'quatruplicity drinks procrastination' is true" is false, and therefore, not nonsense.

Comment: You say a distinction is being made. In his book *Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy* he makes no such distinction, in fact, he claims they mean the same. As for Principia Mathematica, in its introduction he says "*Thus when a text-book of logic asserts that “A is A,” without any indication as to what A may be, what is meant is that any statement of the form “A is A” is true*", supporting the non-distinction you claim to exist. Can you please pinpoint where such a distinction is made?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285194/why-implication-phi-x-rightarrow-psi-x-is-always-true-according-to-russel).

Comment: It's in chapter II of introduction. 
 
At the beginning of this section, it says "the values of the function are propositions," from which I infer the authors wanted to say the values of a propositional function are not truth-values.
 
And in his _An Inquiry into Meaning and Truth_ (First published in 1940), there are similar distinctions, from which I infer Russell didn't change his mind regarding this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible interpretation of the passage must take into account the context, that is : *Chapter II : THE THEORY OF LOGICAL TYPES*.

In particular, the passage is taken from section *II. The Nature of Propositional Functions*.

We must remember the lack of clear and systematic distinction in W&R's *Principia* between object-language and meta-language (and meta-theory); in this chapter, they are explaining the "syntactical" restrictions involved in *type theory*.

See page 40 :

> Now given a function $ \phi(\hat{x})$, the values for the function are all propositions
>   of the form $\phi x$. It follows that there must be no propositions, of the form $\phi x$, in which $x$ has a value which involves $\phi \hat x$.
>
> That is to say, the symbol " $\phi (\phi \hat x$) " must not express a proposition, as
>   " $\phi a$ " does if $\phi a$ is a value for $\phi \hat x$. In fact " $\phi (\phi \hat x$) "  must be a symbol which does not express anything: we may therefore say that it is not significant.

Roughly, the formula $\phi(\phi)$ is **not** *true* **nor** *false*; it is simply *meaningless*, because it violates what we today will call the "rules of formation"; see page 41 :

> Since "$(x) . \phi x$ " involves the function $\phi \hat x$, it must, according to our
>   principle, be impossible as an argument to $\phi$. That is to say, the symbol " $ \phi \{(x) . \phi x \} $ " must be meaningless.

**Gregory Landini**, in *Russell's Hidden Substitutional Theory* (1998), page 279,  proposes a reading that starts from Frege's hierarchy of "levels" of functions.
According to Landini :

> The idea is that a "function" (i.e., a predicate variable) can occur in a subject position (argument position) of another predicate variable only if this position represents a predicate position in the semantics [Landini points to pages 47 and 48 of *PM*].

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro. "$\phi(a)$ is true" looks cumbersome, but according to [this book](https://archive.org/stream/BertrandRussell-AnInquaryIntoMeaningAndTruth/AnInquiryIntoMeaningAndTruth#page/n193/mode/2up/search/%22William+the+Conqueror+1066%22) page 179, most of educated knowledge(as opposed to personal experiences) is actually of this type. Taking this as a hint, I think the first one is supposed to invoke a mental image; the second one is merely or mostly verbal.

Comment: By PM's standards, "$\phi(x)$ is true" is one order above $\phi(x)$. That's the technical difference.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is that "Socrates is a man" is a sentence in the sense that it has a truth value, but we do not make any claim as to what that truth value may be. The claim that "Socrates is a man" is true, is asserting not only that the same sentence has a truth value, but also that that truth value is True.

Just to round things off: "Socrates slept quickly" is not even a sentence since it has no truth value at all, it is simply nonsense written in a grammatically plausible fashion. However, "Socrates had exactly 100,000 hairs on his head by his 18th birthday" is a sentence. It may be true or false, but we'll never know.

I hope this is at all in the right direction to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @Ittay. That helps. Look like I need to improve my understanding of what an assertion is in this context.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, please use Mathjax if you can, and ASCII if you can't. Those symbols don't work for everyone.

Comment: @dfeuer, Wilco.

Comment: Can I say "'$\phi(a)$ is true' is false" implies "'$\phi(a)$ is false' or '$\phi(a)$ is nonsense'?"

Comment: @George Chen - I think we must pay attention to **not** mixing : *(i)* the interpretation of W&R's *PM*, with *(ii)* modern usage in mathematical logic. About *(i)*, the issues regarding the correct interpretation of *PM*'s "philosophical" parts, like the motivation behind type-theory, are complex. About *(ii)*, the distinction between language and meta-language was at the core of Tarski's truth definition and Ramsey's approach to "semantic" paradoxes (like "the Liar").

Comment: Here is a thought experiment: 1. Suppose I'm sitting in a chair, then I stand up and sit back down; 2. I'm blinded folded and led into a room. A most trusted friend of mine told me there is a chair behind me and I cautiously sit down. There is definitely a difference between the two manners I sit down. In the first case, I believed there is a chair behind me, although this belief is pre-verbal. In the second case, I believed there is a chair behind me is true, which is mostly verbal.

Comment: Shame on me. I will not use "thought experiment" again. That is so un-empirical.

Answer (score 2):

I have never read or otherwise studied the Principia; however, I think the general distinction to which Russell is alluding is still very much a recognized principle in modern (formalized) mathematics. Its basically the difference between a sentence $\varphi,$ versus the metasentence $\vdash \varphi$.

Conceptually, the distinction is best explained with reference to partially ordered sets (hereafter *poset*). In a poset, we can assert $x \leq y$ (intuitively, $x$ entails $y$). We may also have a meet-semilattice structure, in which case our assertions can be more sophisticated: we may write $x \wedge x' \leq y,$ intuitively asserting that $x$ and $x',$ taken together, entail $y$.

Note that $\wedge$ is a function, $\leq$ a relation.

Now furthermore, any given meet-semilattice may or may not admit the existence of a function $\rightarrow$ with the following property.

- $x \wedge x' \leq y$ iff $x \leq x' \rightarrow y$.

If such a function exists, it is unique, by [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_Galois_connections) result. (If it is not clear what the above definition has to do with Galois connections, please comment and I will clarify.)

Anyway, if there *is* such a function (which I will call "implication"), then it can be added to the language (alongside $\wedge$ and $\leq$) to get a more expressive language. And we can prove the basic facts we expect from implication, such as [modus ponens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens):

$$(x \rightarrow y) \wedge x \leq y$$

By the way, I recommend saying $\leq$ as "entails", and $\rightarrow$ as "implies", although this is not standardized.

Anyway, the point is that $\rightarrow$ can be conceived as an internalization of $\leq.$ Note that $\rightarrow$ is a function, while $\leq$ is a relation. Thus, spiritually, we can think of $x \rightarrow y$ as a statement *internal* to the language, while a formula like $x \leq y$ can (kind of) be viewed as part of the metalanguage. I am speaking *very* informally, here, of course.

Now I haven't really explained *how* $\rightarrow$ is an internalization of $\leq$, so lets do that. It turns out that if a function $\rightarrow$ with the property of interest exists, then so too does a top element, so long as we're working in a non-empty poset. (Hint: consider the expression $x \rightarrow x$). Denote the top element $\top;$ we can think of this as denoting unadulterated truthood. Furthermore, it can be shown that $x \leq y$ is equivalent to $\top \leq (x \rightarrow y)$. This is the sense in which $\rightarrow$ is an internalization of $\leq$.

Finally, lets switch to more logical notation. Instead of $\leq$, write $\vdash$ (this can also be articulated: "entails"). And lets move to greek letters, which can be thought of as denoting logical formulae. Furthermore, as shorthand for $\top \vdash \varphi$, let us write $\vdash \varphi.$

Then there is a clear difference between $\varphi$, and $\vdash \varphi$.

However, oftentimes $\varphi$ can be used as shorthand for $\vdash \varphi$, if the meaning is clear in context. Similarly, sometimes $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ can be used as shorthand for $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$, or in other words $\varphi \vdash \psi$.

I think this is (at least conceptually) the distinction to which Russell is alluding.

Comment: I appreciate your perspective.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, you're welcome. Feel free to comment with any questions you may have.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not that complicated. My goal here is to be able to "see" this distinction instead of artificially creating a verbal habit.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, perhaps I overcomplicated it by trying to emphasize aspects of order theory that I find interesting and pertinent. The key point was that, in order theory, the formula $\top \leq x$ is different from the expression $x$. The latter is kind of like $\phi(a)$, while the former is kind of like "$\phi(a)$ is true." That's really all that truly needed to be said.

Comment: Thanks, @user18921. The result I hope to achieve here is a direct, instinctive type, rather than a concept derived from other concepts. Let me put this question in the English community and see what I get.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, fair enough. Good luck!

Comment: @GeorgeChen - *user18921*'s answer : "Its basically the difference between a sentence $\phi$, versus the metasentence $\vdash \phi$" point (for me) in the right direction. I think that the historically perspective can be useful. The symbol "$\vdash$" dates back to Frege, in *Begriffsschrift* (1879) [pag.11 of van Heijenoort edition] : "A judgement will always be expressed by means of the sign $\vdash$ [...]. If we *omit* the small vertical stroke at the left end of the horizontal one, the judgement will be transformed into a *mere combination of ideas* [*Vorstellungsverbindung*] ..." 1/3

Comment: "... of which the writer does not state whether he acknowledges it to be true or not. For example, let $\vdash A$ stand for the judgment "Opposite magnetic poles attract each other"; then $\textminus A$ will not express this judgment; [...] When the vertical stroke is omitted, we express ourselves *paraphrastically*, using the words "the circumstance that" or "the proposition that". Not every content becomes a judgment when $\vdash$ is written before its sign; for example, the "house" does not. We therefore distinguish contents that *can become a judgment* form those that *cannot*." 2/3

Comment: So, I think, historical context can help us : W&R are pointing to the distiction between using a symbol for expressing "a content" and the *assertion* that that content "is a fact", i.e.making a *judgment*. Modern usage of $\vdash$ to mean "is a theorem" dtaes back to Rosser and Kleene (1934-35) [see Kleene, *Mathematical Logic* (1967), pag.36, footnote 30]. The link, I suppose, is this : you can have a formula $\phi$ of your language, and it can be true or false (or neither, if it not *closed*). When you assert $\vdash \phi$ you are asserting (in the metalanguage) that you have a proof of it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Theory of Types, "Clifford the Red Dog is not a colour" is nonsense, but "'Clifford the Red Dog is a colour' is not true" is meaningful.

Let $a$ be an individual, $\beta$ be a class of individuals, $\kappa$ a class of classes, $a \in \beta$ is either true or false, $\beta \in \kappa $ is either true or false, but $a \in \kappa$ is nonsense. You can't say $a \notin \kappa$, but you can say "$a \in \kappa$ is not true."

"$\sin(0) = 0$" is true; "$\sin(0) = 1 $" is false; but "$\sin(Socrates) = 0.5 $" is neither true nor false, it is nonsense. "$a \notin \kappa$" is as meaningless as "$sin(Socrates) = 0.5$".

When $\phi(x)$ is not true, $\phi(x)$ can be either false or nonsense.

A sentence that is significant but fails to form a corresponding mental state due to the reader's lack of experience is merely verbal and is nonsense to such a reader. The following is an excerpt from Huxley's *Brave New World*. It demonstrates the difference between "$\phi(x)$" and "$\phi(x)$ is true."

> At breakfast the next morning, "Tommy," some one says, "do you  know
>   which is the longest river in Africa?" A shaking of the head. "But 
>   don't you remember something that begins: The Nile is the ..."
>
> "The - Nile - is - the - longest - river - in - Africa - and - the -
>   second -  in - length - of - all - the - rivers - of - the - globe
>   ..." The words come  rushing out. "Although - falling - short - of
>   ..."
>
> "Well now, which is the longest river in Africa?"
>
> The eyes are blank. "I don't know."
>
> "But the Nile, Tommy."
>
> "The - Nile - is - the - longest - river - in - Africa - and - second
>   ..."
>
> "Then which river is the longest, Tommy?"
>
> Tommy burst into tears. "I don't know," he howls.)

Comment: It took me two months of brooding to make this connection.