# If we accept a false statement, can we prove anything?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I think that the question is contained in the title.
Suppose we begin from something that is false for example $1=0$.
Is it possible using only $\Rightarrow$ (and of course $\lnot ,\wedge,\lor$)  to prove *any* possible statement?
It has been ages since i studied logic at the university so i would prefer a simple explanation
(*if possible*)

Comment: Related: [Why is it possible to conclude everything from a false statement?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53777/why-is-it-possible-to-conclude-everything-from-a-false-statement) (which is itself a duplicate of two other questions, but has a good answer there, so I'm linking to it).

Comment: http://xkcd.com/704/ :)

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148210/can-the-principle-of-explosion-be-removed-from-constructive-logic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If we accept a false statement, can we prove everything?

If by "false" we mean **contradictory,** then the answer is *yes*, by the [principle of explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). For example, begin with the Peano axioms and adjoin the sentence $1=0$. Then since it is already a theorem of the Peano axioms that $1 \neq 0$, we have a contradiction. We say that the resulting system is "inconsistent" (meaning, it has a contradiction), and therefore satisfies the conditions under which the principle of explosion can be invoked.

Now on the other hand, if by "false" we mean **unsound,** then the answer is *not necessarily.* For example, begin once again with the Peano axioms, but this time adjoin an additional axiom that says "the Peano axioms are inconsistent." Paradoxically, this does not entail a contradiction. Therefore, we **cannot** prove everything. For example, pick any sentence $\varphi$ in the language of the Peano axioms; we cannot prove both $\varphi$ and $\neg \varphi$ in the system under discussion. Nonetheless, we accepted a statement (namely, that the Peano axioms are inconsistent) which is almost surely false.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a truth table to prove that $P\implies [\neg P\implies Q]$.

In words, if we know that $P$ is true, but we assume, for the sake of argument, that $P$ is false (i.e. $\neg P)$, then *any* proposition $Q$ can be derived.

We can also prove this theorem as follows:

1. Suppose $P$
2. Suppose $\neg P$
3. Suppose $\neg Q$
4. We obtain the contradiction $P\land \neg P$
5. Therefore, we must have $\neg\neg Q$, or equivalently $Q$
6. Therefore, $\neg P \implies Q$
7. Therefore, $P\implies [\neg P\implies Q]$

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Natural Deduction (rif.*Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges*, **Mathematical Logic**, 2007), - pag.25 - you have the ($\lnot$-intro) rule (or RAA : Reductio Ad Absurdum) :

> suppose we have a derivation $D \Rightarrow \bot$ whose conclusion is $\bot$ , then there is a derivation  $D' \Rightarrow \phi$ whose assumptions are those of $D$, except possiby $(\lnot \phi)$ (where - pag.24 - $\bot$ is a statement which is definitely false (absurdity)).

In a "traditional" approach, you will exploit the tautology : $A \rightarrow (\lnot A \rightarrow B)$ ; but you need a *contradiction* and not a false statement.

Only if you are working in a theory like first-order Peano Arithmetic, where you can prove that $1 \neq 0$ (i.e. $\vdash  \lnot 1 = 0$ ), from your assumption $1=0$, with the above tautology, you can derive $B$ (whatever).

Answer (score 2):

Any theorem is based on axioms and established theorems. So when you add a deductive theorem to your system of theorems. You have to guarantee your system is self-consistent. Otherwise, the system is nonsense.

Of course you can add $1=0$ in your system of theorems, but I don't know what's your established system. In ring theory, $1=0$ implies a trivial ring and that's totally fine. But if $1=0$ is based on axioms of natural numbers, then you can derive anything since "$1=0$"$\to q$ is true whatever $q$ is because $1=0$ is false. But, certainly, what you derived from $1=0$ may contracts with established theorems or axioms in system of theorems.