# Doubt on Implication of Logical reasoning

Tags: logic

Its evident that in the truth table of $p \to q$

When $p$ is False and $q$ is True, Then $p \to q$ is True.

But in some instances i could not convince myself about this truth value.

For example:

$p$: Quadrilateral is Cyclic

$q$: Opposite angles are supplementary

Now is $p$ is False and $q$ is True, how can $p \to q$ can be True?

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53777/why-is-it-possible-to-conclude-everything-from-a-false-statement?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616295/if-we-accept-a-false-statement-can-we-prove-anything?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168282/truth-table-for-if-p-then-q?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I've marked this as a possible duplicate of "[In classical logic, why is $(p\Rightarrow q)$ True if $p$ is False and $q$ is True?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr)"